# Asp MVC parameters not mapping even though values are being posted

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a simple form with a hidden field that stores a date and a visible field for the user to upload a file:

```
<form method="post" action="/TestController/SaveCsv">
    <div class="toolbar-item">
        <div class="toolbar-label">Upload CSV:</div>
        <div class="toolbar-value">
            <input type="hidden" id="uploadCsvAuthorisedDate" name="uploadCsvAuthorisedDate" data-bind="value: authorisedDate" />
            <input type="file" id="uploadCsv" name="uploadCsv" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="toolbar-item">
        <button type="submit">Upload CSV</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's the c# controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveCsv(DateTime uploadCsvAuthorisedDate, HttpPostedFileBase uploadCsv)
{
    //additional processing code not important
}
```

**The problem:**
The file upload field is populated correctly, but the uploadCsvAuthorisedDate is not.

If I run the following in the immediate debug window:

```
Request.Form[0]
Output: Fri May 22 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)
```

I get the date that I was expecting.

**Question:** Is this a case of the date format being wrong or perhaps parameter mapping doesn't like the hidden field?

Comment: Does the posted date format match the `DateTime` format of the server? (there is no problem mapping a hidden field)

Comment: @StephenMuecke apologies I forgot to add a sample of the date format. I've edited my question to add a sample

Comment: Feels like a format problem

Comment: You can test if its valis using `DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(Request.Form[0]);` - if it throws an exception then its not a valid format. but since its a hidden field and not for editing, you can always set the value to ISO format - `yyyy-MM-dd` which will always be bound irrespective of the server culture

Comment: @StephenMuecke it is a format problem yes. Thanks I didn't think about testing the formatting. The problem now is that the hidden field that holds the date is subscribed to an MVVM observable property (Knockout) so I'm not sure how I would change that date before posting apart from actually binding to the post event of the form.

Comment: I don't use knockout so no sure if there is a simple solution, but you could always use javascript (intercept the submit and modify the value) using `var date = new (Date($('#uploadCsvAuthorisedDate').val()); $('#uploadCsvAuthorisedDate').val(date.toISOString());`

Comment: try String uploadCsvAuthorisedDate,in parameter and check if you are getting this or not ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke do you want to go ahead and add your idea as an answer. I managed to resolve it by using toISOString() in the binding.

Comment: Happy for you to add the answer with the actual code you used :)